# Unknown system variable 'show_compatibility_56

Tags: mysql, docker

I have created a docker image and installed and got MySQL up and running.   I'm trying to restore a dump file and I'm getting

> ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 3184: Unknown system variable
> 'show_compatibility_56'

I tried to set the variable in the Workbench but I get variable not found.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get a DB Dump to restore?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `MySQL 8+` the show_compatibility_56 system variable is removed

> Beyond MySQL 5.7
>
> In a MySQL 8.0, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA variable tables and the
> show_compatibility_56 system variable are removed, and output from the
> SHOW statements is always based on the underlying Performance Schema
> tables.
>
> Applications that have been revised to work in MySQL 5.7 when
> show_compatibility_56=OFF should work without further changes, except
> that it is not possible to test or set show_compatibility_56 because
> it does not exist.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-variable-table-migration.html

Comment: So what do I do to get around the error if I want to import a DB?

Comment: @CrazyHarry try  [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942948/ubuntu-16-04-with-lamp-mysql-5-7-show-compatibility-56) and let me know if it helps

Comment: 09:56:01 set @@global.show_compatibility_56=ON Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'show_compatibility_56' 0.000 sec

Comment: @CrazyHarry try below method step by step
 1. sudo sed -n '/show_compatibility_56/=' your_dump.sql ---> it will print the line containing  the string "show_compatibility_56" 
2. sudo sed -n 39p your_dump.sql --->it will print the full line 39. change 39 with the line resulting from the first sed  
3. sed -i 's/show_compatibility_56//' your_dump.sql ---> will remove the string show_compatibility_56 from the dump